# Fine tune xrightarrow subscript

Tags: xrightarrow

Consider the following output:

[image]

How to move **only** `=` up a little bit? The equal sign is too near the line below it.

I have tried

```
\newcommand{\seta}[1][]{\xrightarrow[\raisebox{1pt}{\makebox[1ex]{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle=}}}]{#1}}
```

but changing `1pt` to `4pt` for example, moves also the line below (at least according to my eyes).

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\newcommand{\seta}[1][]{\xrightarrow[=]{#1}}
\begin{document}
$a\seta b$ \quad
$a\seta[G]b$ \quad
$a\seta[\mathcal{F}(G)]b$ \lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe with `\vphantom` and `\smash`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}
\newcommand{\seta}[1][]{\xrightarrow[\vphantom{=}\smash{\raisebox{0.3ex}{=}}]{#1}}
\begin{document}
$a\seta b$ \quad
$a\seta[G]b$ \quad
$a\seta[\mathcal{F}(G)]b$ \lipsum*[2]

\renewcommand{\seta}[1][]{\xrightarrow[\vphantom{=}\smash{\raisebox{0ex}{=}}]{#1}}

$a\seta b$ \quad
$a\seta[G]b$ \quad
$a\seta[\mathcal{F}(G)]b$ \lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The lower example is just for comparison.

Comment: Interesting. So, the first output raises a little bit and compared to the normal one, the second output, it is visible the difference. Great.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a lower level, but more flexible, construct.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\eqxrightarrow}[1]{\mathrel{\eq@xrightarrow{#1}}}

\newcommand{\eq@xrightarrow}[1]{%
  \mathop{%
    \vtop{%
      \m@th % no extra space around math
      \offinterlineskip % disable glue between lines
      \ialign{%
        % one column, center align
        \hfil##\hfil\cr
        % fill the row with a right arrow
        \rightarrowfill\cr
        % width is at least the superscript plus 16 mu
        \hphantom{$\scriptstyle\mskip8mu{#1}\mskip8mu$}\cr
        % and at least 1.5em
        \vrule height0pt width 1.5em\cr
        % bottom row is =
        $\scriptstyle=$\cr
      }%
    }%
  }\limits^{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\eqxrightarrow{} b$ \quad
$a\eqxrightarrow{G} b$ \quad
$a\eqxrightarrow{\mathcal{F}(G)} b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing construction. Thanks a lot for comments in the code. I'll study it.